# Sorting Realm results collection on computed property?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, computed-properties

I'm using Realm in my Swift iOS app and I have a model that I'm trying to add a computed property to.  Here's what the class looks like:

```
class Conversation: Object {

    @objc dynamic var conversationId: String = generateConversationId()
    @objc dynamic var createdTime = Date()
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    let messages = List<Message>()

    var lastUpdated: Date {
        if let newestMessage = self.messages.sorted(byKeyPath: "timestamp", ascending: false).first {
            return newestMessage.timestamp
        } else {
            return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
        }
    }        
}
```

As you can see, this object represents a conversation which has several properties one of which is a list of messages that belong to the conversation.  The computed property that I've added (`lastUpdated`) should just return the timestamp of the most recent message in the `messages` list or, when the list is empty, it would return a default date value.

In one of my view controllers, I'm creating a results collection to access the `Conversation` objects like this:

```
var conversations: Results<Conversation> = realm.objects(Conversation.self)
```

This works and I can access the `lastUpdated` property on each `Conversation` as expected.  However, I'd like to have this collection sorted by the `lastUpdated` property so I tried modifying my results collection like this:

```
var conversations: Results<Conversation> = realm.objects(Conversation.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "lastUpdated", ascending: true)
```

When I do this, the app throws the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot sort on key path 'lastUpdated': property 'Conversation.lastUpdated' does not exist.'
```

I *think* this might be happening because the `lastUpdated` computed property isn't persisted on the `Conversation` object (I would use Realm Studio to quickly verify this but my Realm is encrypted).  I'm not explicitly ignoring this property but I assume this is the case because `lastUpdated` is not decorated with `@objc dynamic` like all of my other properties.  I tried adding that, wiping my app install, recompiling and testing again but I still end up with the same exception.

Maybe it's not possible to persist a computed property (because, well, it's computed!) but is there another way to specify that my Conversation results collection should be sorted by this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, you cannot persist a computed property and `Realm`'s `sorted(byKeyPath:,ascending:)` method only works with persisted properties. There is no way to sort a `Results` instance based on a computed property while keeping the auto-updating `Results`.

However, there is a workaround if you don't need the auto-updating nature of `Results`. You can use Swift's `sorted` method, which takes a closure as its sorting parameter, which will result in a return value of type `[Conversation]`:

```
let conversations = realm.objects(Conversation.self).sorted(by: {$0.lastUpdated < $1.lastUpdated})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Unfortunately, I do need the auto-updating aspect of Results (I'm also using a notification token to observe changes and update a UITableView accordingly).

Comment: @bmt22033 then why you accepted this answer? I have the same problem, did you find another solution?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?